# How to submit a form with several input[@type='submit'] using rvest?

Tags: rvest

I would like to use `rvest` to list all items in shopping cart and save for later. I scraped my cart using the following:

```
session <- html_session(url)
cart_form <- html_form(session)[[3]]

# get all fields
fileds <- cart_form$fields
```

Each field is in the following format:

```
$`submit.save-for-later.C3219bd67-8845-4b3f-a9ba-4c10233249f0`
<field> (submit) submit.save-for-later.C3219bd67-8845-4b3f-a9ba-4c10233249f0: Save for later
```

And the input element on the web page looks like this:

```
<input name="submit.save-for-later.C3219bd67-8845-4b3f-a9ba-4c10233249f0" value="Save for later" data-action="save-for-later" aria-label="Save for later item&amp;quot; H x 7&amp;quot; - Random stuff" type="submit" class="a-color-link">
```

Now, I want to list out all the `input[@type='submit']` and create click behavior.

```
for(field in fields){
    data_action = field$attr['data-action']

    if(data_action == 'save-for-later'){
        session_submit(session, cart_form, submit=field$name)

    }
}
```

but I get `Error: All components of query must be named`.

I also tried creating a button with a name and submitting, but it says  `No <input> found with name 'button'.`

I'm at an impasse and I don't know how to solve it.